# Extract content between comas (and more) in a vector in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataframe from a .csv file with 4 variables:

```
str(statementGS)
$ X                : int ...
$ statement_type_cd: Factor ...
$ statement_text   : Factor ...
$ serial_no        : int ...
```

I need to work with the `statement_text` vector (9629704 rows):

```
                                                                            statement_text
1                                                                                  pistols
2                                                      CORDS, LINES, [ TWINES, ] AND ROPES
3                                                  POCKET AND TABLE CUTLERY *silver color*
4                         (Based on intent) Nail brushes; Lip brushes; and Make-up brushes
5                                                                      ICE CREAM FREEZERS.
...        
9629702  Contract workflows, and data analytics. The SAAS feature technology for contracts  
9629703                                  ADVANCED COMBAT SURVEILLANCE DROW (LOW ENDURANCE)
9629704                  Health spa; namely, cosmetic body care services; ((beauty salon))
```

I've been trying to extract every product name between comas into a new vector with regular expressions with no success (using a subset of the dataframe).

I think the sequence of the regurlar expression should be something like this:

1. Delete every `.` at the end of a cell
2. Change every `[`  `]`  `((`  `))`  `;`  `.` for comas `,`
3. Delete everything between `*` `*` and the `*` themselves
4. Delete every `namely` or `-namely`
5. Delete every `and` after a coma
6. If a `(` begins with `Based on` delete everything inside the `()` and the `()`themselves
7. Now, look at the vector, if there are `,` in the cell, copy the content between them into a new vector but skip if there is only blank spaces between the `,` (don't know how to program this for the first and last element), if there are not, just copy the cell to the new vector.

   - (It would be nice to not copy an element if it is already in the new vector i.e. not copying `t-shirt` 1000 times, but maybe it is easier to get the new vector and then deleting the cells that have the same characters as another one before them).

I've been reading the documentation and, if I'm not mistaken, the first 5 steps would be done with the `gsub` function and then an if/else loop would be needed to get the new vector.

The desired outcome:

```
         Products
1        pistols
2        CORDS 
3        LINES
4        TWINES
5        ROPES
6        POCKET AND TABLE CUTLERY
7        Nail brushes
8        Lip brushes 
9        Make-up brushes
10       ICE CREAM FREEZERS
...
20000000 ADVANCED COMBAT SURVEILLANCE DROW (LOW ENDURANCE)
20000001 Health spa 
20000002 cosmetic body care services 
20000003 beauty salon
20000004 Contract workflows 
20000005 data analytics 
20000006 The SAAS feature technology for contracts
```

PS: I'm new to R (and programming) but I noticed that when using `typeof` with the vector it returns that it is an integer, isn't that strange? :thinking:

```
typeof(statementGS$statement_text)
[1] "integer"
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: for a question like this, it would help if you provided a reproducible example.  Like, post a code snippet would someone could copy/paste into their r session to have the example dataframe or vector you have.

Comment: 1) add stringsAsFactors = FALSE when you read the csv, to treat the oclumnas character. 2) the package `stringr` has more robust string functions.  3) this is moslty  about regex - suggest you find an online site that lets you test regexes.

Comment: @epi99 You are completely right, didnt know about that argument for the read.table function, it worked perfect. I will use the webs you suggest to try to solve my problem, thanks. Dan the example of statement_text I wrote isn't good? I wanted to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this some time ago but forgot to answer.

```
gsub("\\.(?=\\n$)", "", statement_text);
gsub(";", ",", statement_text);
gsub("((", ",", statement_text);
gsub("))", ",", statement_text);
gsub("[", ",", statement_text);
gsub("]", ",", statement_text);
gsub("namely", "", statement_text, ignore.case=T);
gsub("-namely", "", statement_text, ignore.case=T);
gsub("namely:", "", statement_text, ignore.case=T);
gsub("namely,", "", statement_text, ignore.case=T);
gsub(",and", "", statement_text, ignore.case=T);
gsub(";and", "", statement_text, ignore.case=T);
gsub("\(Based on.*\)", "", statement_text, ignore.case=T);
gsub("^ ", "", statement_text);
gsub("\*.*2\*", "", statement_text);
gsub("\{.*2\}", "", statement_text);
#Replace commas with new lines, when doing this if the dataframe has X rows
#it won't add new rows (a lot of info would be lost), so I did it with notepad++ 
#find and replace function.
#If you now how to do this in R say so in comments please. 
gsub(",", "\\n", statement_text);
gsub(""", "", statement_text);
```